# Unable to populate NSMutableArray from JSON file

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutablearray

I have this following code that I am using to populate an NSMutableArray from a JSON file to use it late as a datasource for a CollectionView:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"governorates" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *content = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSDictionary *governorateJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:content options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSArray *govNSArray = [governorateJson objectForKey:@"gouvernorats"];
if ([govNSArray isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){
    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in govNSArray) {
        Governorate *govModel = [Governorate new] ;
        govModel.govID = [dictionary objectForKey:@"id"];
        govModel.govNameAr = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"nom"] objectForKey:@"ar"];
        govModel.govNameFr = [[dictionary objectForKey:@"nom"] objectForKey:@"fr"];
        [self.governoratesArray addObject:govModel];
        [self.governoratesString addObject:govModel.govNameAr];
        NSLog(@"Count: %lu", (unsigned long) self.governoratesString.count);
    }
    NSLog(@"Total Count: %lu", (unsigned long) self.governoratesString.count);
}
```

The problem is the `NSMutableArray` always seems to be empty, and I am using the exact same code in another place with the same JSON file and it's working fine.

Comment: What do you get for your `NSLog` statements?  Are you getting the data returned that you expect?

Comment: I've got 0 element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once check that mutable array is being alloc init or not before using it.

Comment: Thanks @Akshay, It seems that I forgot to alloc the array

Answer (score 0):

Do you create a new empty mutable array anywhere? If you don't then addObject isn't going to do anything.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

U have to check what kind of data u are getting after serializing data that is array or dictionary format .And also the check the json response format before parsing ....

One more suggestion is to try "Value for Key " instead of object for key

```
 NSMutableAray *arry= [governorateJson      
     valueForKey:@"gouvernorats"];
```

Comment: Absolutely DON'T use valueForKey. Read its documentation, then tell us why you would want to use that monstrosity.